# PHP "str_replace" doesn't work properly in some case?

Tags: php, sql-server, csv, str-replace

The below is the php code i am using

```
$file_handle = fopen("products.csv", "r");
$fname = "products.csv";
$fhandle = fopen($fname,"r");
$content = fread($fhandle,filesize($fname));
$server = "**\******,1433";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"******", "UID"=>"***", "PWD"=>"*******" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $server, $connectionInfo ); 

if( $conn === false ) {
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    $itemco = $line_of_text[0];
    $sql = "SELECT quantity FROM Item WHERE itemlookupcode = '$itemco' "; 
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );

    if( $stmt === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    }

    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        $icc = $row['quantity'];
        $content = str_replace("$line_of_text[1]", "$icc", "$content");
    }
}

$fhandle = fopen($fname,"w");
fwrite($fhandle,$content);
fclose($fhandle);
```

`str_replace` isn't working in the following instance:

```
$content = str_replace("$line_of_text[1]", "$icc", "$content");
```

Comment: Get rid of the quotes around your variable names inside of `str_replace()`

Comment: @JohnConde is right, its taking the literal characters "$icc" and "$content"

Comment: Thanks i tried it before but it doesn't work.

Comment: can you add little more detail, 3 2 value examples. What comes in $line_of_text, $icc and $content. str_replace needs to do replacement and it will do whenever possible.

Comment: The quotes would be irrelevant in this case; it's only single quotes that preserve the literal dollar sign. They still do not need to (and should not) be there however.

Comment: Why you are using double quotes in str_replace parameters..? they are variables..

Comment: Double quotes are okay, its not an issue, even its better to use it in case if its not an string, it will be converted to string instead of throwing error. Can you please define: str_replace is "NOT WORKING". What do you mean by "not working"? What are you expecting and what is the value that you are getting ? You can break the loop  and check the content of variables and output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you open the same file three times and only close it once. This is not a major problem but you really should make a habit of finishing/closing what you started. You can skip one of those `fopen` by using `file_get_contents`:

```
$content = file_get_contents("products.csv");
```

Now, `str_replace` will replace **every** occurrence of your string. If, for example,  `$line_of_text[1]` is "11" and `$icc` is "9", other values in the file such as "110" will be affected, thus making the rest of future replacements less and less reliable each loop.

If I'm not mistaken and all you want to do is replace a single cell in each row, here's a suggestion:
Create an empty variable, let's say `$new_content`

Now, change your loop:

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $line_of_text[1] = $row['quantity']; // change cell value
    $new_content .= implode(',', $line_of_text).','; // convert into string with extra
                                                     // ',' to avoid merging cells
}
$new_content = trim($new_content, ','); // remove extra ','
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove quotes around variables.

```
$content = str_replace("$line_of_text[1]", "$icc", "$content");
```

Should be

```
$content = str_replace($line_of_text[1], $icc, $content);

//str_replace ( search, replace, subject )   This is how it works.
```

Next,

Use this code corresponding to the while loop

```
$count=1;
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
$icc = $row['quantity'];
$content = str_replace($line_of_text[$count++], $icc, $content);
}
```

Comment: $line_of_text[1] what does this variable have? I see $line_of_text is unassigned in the code you provided

Comment: $line_of_text[1] is number - quantity

Comment: I couldn't get your question completely, but check if my updated answer helps

Comment: It seems you have a problem with the logic in the code. Check what `$content` has, and try to treat each line individually.

Answer (score 1):

No debug output data.. I can only give some advice..

- Does $line_of_text[1] and $icc output as expected values?
- Does sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) returns a proper value? (If not it will won't do anything)
- Hows your csv file structured?

Comment: .Does $line_of_text[1] and $icc output as expected values? Yes.. Does sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) returns a proper value? Yes...Hows your csv file structured? I dont get what this is mean the only problem is when row have same $line_of_text[1] value .. like row 1 $line_of_text[1] = '1' row 2 $line_of_text[1] = '1' except this it works but only each of $line_of_text[1] has same value Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand, but there is no reason that `str_replace` does not work.
It may be just a matter of reasoning.
It does not work at all or only in some cases?
If it is in some cases, it may be because the replacement value no longer exists.

For example:

```
$content = "1234";
echo "$content\n"; // echo "1234"
$content = str_replace("1", "a", "$content");
echo "$content\n"; // echo "a1234"
$content = str_replace("2", "b", "$content");
echo "$content\n"; //  echo "ab34"
$content = str_replace("1", "c", "$content");
echo "$content\n";  // echo "ab34" => no change because '1' is not existe -> already replace
```

I do not know if this is your problem, but it could explain.

So may be you should do something like this:

```
$pos1 = stripos("$content", "$line_of_text[1]");
if ($pos1 !== false)
    $content = str_replace("$line_of_text[1]", "$icc", "$content");
else
    echo "$line_of_text[1] not found in $content \n";
```

Otherwise, I agree with the others, the double quotes are optional. :)

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

$content = str_replace("$line_of_text[1]", "$icc", "$content");

this should be replaced with

$content = str_replace($line_of_text[1], $icc, $content);

since these are php variables and putting them in double or single quotes is incorrect, as they will be considered as normal text and str_replace will try to replace "$line_of_text[1]" with "$icc" in "$content".